# Edit or extend chromes redirect limit

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

I have an internal web app that displays images (among other functions).  Google chrome will inconsistently give me an error when retrieving images (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).  Sometimes I will refresh, and the problem will go away.  Other times I need to clear my cache.

This app was written specifically for google chrome, and has various quirks in other browsers.  To work around this limitation I want to disable or increase the redirect limit in chrome.  I know that this is possible in firefox, but digging through chrome://about I haven't found a control for this limit.  Is this possible in chrome? Thanks!

**Note:  I realize that this is not the correct way to solve this problem.  There are a number of details here that I have omitted for the sake of brevity, and those details make this the path of least resistence (if possible) to solve my problem.**

Comment: I often saw this error when preforming DNS maintenance and server moves where there are DNS redirects at work. I would especially see this when a redirect loop occurred.

Comment: I wouldn't expect DNS aliases to be visible to the browser, they're handled automatically by the resolver. This error should be related to HTTP redirects.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384474/in-chrome-how-many-redirects-are-too-many Chrome's redirect limit is 20. That seems like it should be more than enough for any sensible site, and hitting the limit usually indicates a loop.

Comment: `chrome://flags` provides access to lots of internal, experimental options, but I don't see any mention of redirect there, either.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hardcoded at compile time, so you can't change it: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/url_request/url_request.h;l=97;drc=3c19a2edb96d3d5b56a7481349a357fdbdf8ecf0

```cpp
  // Max number of http redirects to follow. The Fetch spec says: "If
  // request's redirect count is twenty, return a network error."
  // https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-redirect-fetch
  static constexpr int kMaxRedirects = 20;
```